# What is a pull-through cache?

Tags: caching, ehcache

I found a reference to this concept in the [EHCache documentation](http://ehcache.org/documentation/user-guide/constructs), but I could not find any proper explanation of what it means.
It tried Googling around but to no avail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The more common term is *self populating cache*.

In [Ehcache docs](http://ehcache.org/documentation/user-guide/cache-decorators#SelfPopulatingCache) a `SelfPopulatingCache` (= pull-through cache) is described as a:

> A selfpopulating decorator for Ehcache that creates entries on demand.

That means when asking the `SelfPopulatingCache` for a value and that value is not in the cache, it will create this value for you.